# How to use mac-key-mode with Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

I want to use Mac CMD+C for copy and CMD+V for paste in Spacemacs but I think it redefined CMD to Meta. How do I change this mapping behavior?

I found mac-key-mode but that package seems old and I don't know how to add it to Spacemacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the layer OSX to the dotspacemacs-configuration-layers section of your [dotspacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/doc/QUICK_START.html#dotfile-spacemacs) file.
Open dotspacemacs with SPC f e d. Add "OSX" without the quotes to the list of "useful layers" and reload dotspacemacs with SPC f e R.